# Calculating Pascal's Triangle N-th row - why does this work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

I encountered this solution to the problem in the title (calculate Pascal's Triangle $N$-th row). The main point is the calculation within the loop - I am trying to figure out the meaning of it:

> For every $0\leqslant i\leqslant n$:
>   $$\alpha_0 = 1,\quad \alpha_i = \dfrac{\alpha_{i-1}(a+i-1)}{i}.$$

Why is it correct? I assume its related to the binomial coefficients in a way. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexFrancisco fixed to equations. I have no written progress figuring this out, just mentally trying to process this into something recognisable.

Comment: You´ve forgotten to post several definitions. What is $a_i, a, n$ and $i$? From where did you get this?

Comment: @callculus talking about pascal's triangle n-th row, assumed its clear n is the number of the row (zero based), and also the index of the last element in the row. $a_i$ are elements in the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your formula there is related to alisianoi's solution to [this SO question on efficient binomial computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560726/python-binomial-coefficient). Note in the code comments, you 
have the following:

```
Use an iterative approach with the multiplicative formula:
```

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!} =
\frac{n(n - 1)\dots(n - k + 1)}{k(k-1)\dots(1)} =
\prod_{i = 1}^{k}\frac{n + 1 - i}{i}$$

```
Also rely on the symmetry:
```

$C_n^k = C_n^{n - k},$

```
so the product can be calculated up to
```

$\min(k, n - k).$

Comment: Thanks a lot :)